# Array teleports far away from the starting point once curve modification is selected onto path

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bezier-curves, vertices, transforms

[image]

Hello, so i've scaled my object which I modified with the array modifier and it gave me a linear array of the lenght of my numbs path. The Problem is now that i wanted it to curve on the nubs path on the balcony of the house. Therefore I choose to add the curve modifier additionally. When I select the the numbs path tho, the array kind of teleports far away from the starting point which is the red circle on the picture.. How can I stop it to teleport after curving so it fits on my numbs path?

Comment: is your origin point of that object where it should be? This often happens when origin point (orange dot) is outside of the object

Comment: I've shifted the origin point to the middle of my array with shift + S and set it to world origin but it still did't work wehen I applied the curve modifier